# strange phenomenon while dequeuing

Tags: c++, vector, queue

I have created a vector of queues. There are 10 vectors and around 1000 elements in the queue. Then I try to dequeue one element from the in a queue across all the vector in a round-robin fashion. But I observe a very strange phenomenon. I see that some of the vectors have 2 elements dequeued and some have none.

```
struct pkt{
    int data;
    int time;
};

//Input queues are already filled with 1000 packets
std::vector<std::queue<pkt>> per_port_input_queue;
std::vector<std::queue<pkt>> per_port_output_queue;

// Dequeing one element at a time in a round-robin fashion
for(int i=0;i<5; i++)
{
decoded_pkt=per_port_input_queue[i].front();
send_to_output(decoded_pkt);
per_port_input_queue[decoded_pkt.data].pop();
}

void send_to_output(pkt decoded_pkt)
{
     per_port_output_queue[decoded_pkt.data].push(decoded_pkt);

}
```

Below you can find the observed output and my expected output.

```
========================================================
Port       I/p (t=0)  (after dequing        My
                           5 pkt)       Expected result
========================================================
 0         1000          1000               999
 1         1000          1000               999
 2         1000          1000               999
 3         1000          998                999
 4         1000          1000               999
 5         1000          1000              1000
 6         1000          999               1000
 7         1000          999               1000
 8         1000          1000              1000
 9         1000          999               1000
```

Can somebody clarify me why this occurs and how to avoid this. Is there some problem with using queues in c++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Dequeing one element at a time in a round-robin fashion
for(int i=0;i<5; i++)
{
decoded_pkt=per_port_input_queue[i].front();
send_to_output(decoded_pkt);
per_port_input_queue[decoded_pkt.data].pop(); <<<<<======
}
```

the popped queue depends on the data that you read from the i'th queue, so its not surprising. if you mean to read and then pop the same queue u need to go

```
// Dequeing one element at a time in a round-robin fashion
for(int i=0;i<5; i++)
{
decoded_pkt=per_port_input_queue[i].front();
send_to_output(decoded_pkt);
per_port_input_queue[i].pop();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I accept your answer. It was a silly bug :-)